# Increment time and add records in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dictionary

I have some number of records of time-series data and I have to create dummy data if record not present for complete 1 hour with interval of 1 minute.

I am trying to see number of records less from 60 minutes and increment 1 minute from last record until total 60 records not present.

I am trying below method but my code although when doing print statement in loop showing correct timings but in data-frame it shows single value which is the final one in sequence for all dummy inserts, My idea is somehow it's updating all values but not sure how and where ?

Below is my code trying on :

Dictionary type: (fd is a list of dictionary items like below)

```
{'a': 636,
 'b': 'D1016',
 'c': 53.280004,
 'd': 0.0,
 'e': 28.765,
 'time': '2017-12-10 14:54:07'}
```

**code**: (copying existing record and updating the time)

```
length_dict = 53               #len(fd)   - hardcoded for now
if length_dict <= 60:
    row_to_insert = 60-length_dict

last_time = fd[length_dict-1]['time']

for row in range(row_to_insert):
    fd.append(fd[length_dict-1])
    new_len_dict = len(fd)
    #print("lngth of fd:",new_len_dict)
    date = datetime.strptime(last_time , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    modified_date = date + timedelta(minutes=(row+1))
    modified_date = datetime.strftime(modified_date, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    #print(modified_date)
    fd[new_len_dict-1]['time'] = modified_date[:]
    #print(fd[new_len_dict-1]['time'])
```

**Output** : Every inserted records have this structure- total 7 minutes added which should be only for last one.

```
{'a': 636,
 'b': 'D1016',
 'c': 53.280004,
 'd': 0.0,
 'e': 28.765,
 'time': '2017/12/10 15:01:07'}
```

On screen output is in proper sequence:

```
lngth of fd: 54
2017/12/10 14:55:07
lngth of fd: 55
2017/12/10 14:56:07
lngth of fd: 56
2017/12/10 14:57:07
lngth of fd: 57
2017/12/10 14:58:07
lngth of fd: 58
2017/12/10 14:59:07
lngth of fd: 59
2017/12/10 15:00:07
lngth of fd: 60
2017/12/10 15:01:07
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best choice for optimization purpose but it serve my purpose:

Problem I found was when I was appending list `fd` from itself , it's creating reference instead of new list record. So dirty trick I used is copy first the row I have to append from same list.

Just change is in below line and everything worked like charm.

```
fd.append(fd[new_len_dict-1].copy())
```